# VBA code cannot connect to SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, vba

My code cannot connect to the database within Microsoft SQL Server 2008. It tries to but then errors out with the following error: "run time error SQL Server does not exist or access denied. The Server is password protected but I think I accounted for that. Any help would be appreciated! Where the error occurs is bolded

```vb
Public Sub dataextract()

    'Create a connection object.'
     Dim cndatabase_name As ADODB.Connection
     Set cndatabase_name = New ADODB.Connection

    'Provide the connection string.'
     Dim strConn As String

    'Use the SQL Server OLE DB Provider.'
     strConn = "PROVIDER=SQLOLEDB;"

     'Connect to the  database on the  server.'
     strConn = strConn & "DATA SOURCE=Server_name;INITIAL CATALOG=database_name;"

     ' Login details.'
      strConn = strConn & " UID=username; PWD=password"

    'Now open the connection.'
    'ERROR HERE:'
     cndatabase_name.Open strConn***




    ' Create a recordset object.'
    Dim rsdatabase_name As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rsdatabase_name = New ADODB.Recordset

    With rsdatabase_name
        ' Assign the Connection object.'
        .ActiveConnection = cndatabase_name
        ' Extract the required records.'
        .Open "SELECT * FROM table_name"
        ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.'
        Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsdatabase_name

        ' Tidy up'
        .Close
    End With

    cndatabase_name
    Set rsdatabase_name = Nothing
    Set cndatabase_name = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I have added the string "Trusted_Connection=Yes" & changed the provider to "SQLNCLI10"

I now get an error stating: "named pipes provider could not open a connection to sql server [53]"

Comment: Ok. I got connected to the server and now I am getting an object required error on this line:

 Sheet1.SetRange("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsDataBaseName

Comment: Changed it to: "ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.SetRange("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsSikich_CWManager"

Got an object does not support this property error

Comment: Got everything working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
' Create a recordset object.'
Dim rsdatabase_name As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsdatabase_name = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsdatabase_name
    ' Assign the Connection object.'
    .ActiveConnection = cndatabase_name
    ' Extract the required records.'
    .Open "SELECT * FROM table_name"
    ' Copy the records into cell A1 on Sheet1.'
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsdatabase_name

    ' Tidy up'
    .Close
End With

cndatabase_name
Set rsdatabase_name = Nothing
Set cndatabase_name = Nothing
```

to

```
' Create a recordset object.'
Dim rsdatabase_name As ADODB.Recordset
Set rsdatabase_name = New ADODB.Recordset

With rsdatabase_name
    ' Assign the Connection object.'
    .ActiveConnection = cndatabase_name
    ' Extract the required records.'
    .Open "SELECT * FROM table_name"
    ' Tidy up'
    .Close
End With

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsdatabase_name

Set rsdatabase_name = Nothing
Set cndatabase_name = Nothing
```

You have a random "cndatabase_name" sitting in your code.

:)

Comment: Removed it but the error still persists at that:

"Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsdatabase_name" line.

Comment: Yes it is the same error. I think it has something to do with the range value. Basically I am trying to pull data from sql into an excel spreadsheet starting in cell A1.

Comment: Go to your VBA project-> References and make sure that Microsoft ActiveX Data objects 2.x library is included. if it's not, include it and try the code again.

Comment: It is included. Someone just gave me a clue and said use something like mywb.sheet1.setrange. That is not working either though. I think it is an issue with VBA not knowing where to drop the data

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing it through VBA at all? You could do this easily through a sql connection. I don't see anything wrong with the code itself though

Comment: Changed it to: "ActiveWorkbook.Sheet1.SetRange("A1").CopyFromRecordset rsSikich_CWManager"

Got an object does not support this property error

Comment: Because that isn't a declared record set as far as I can see

Comment: It's a specific assignment to do it through VBA. The person wants to be able to write a sql query in excel, click a button (that references the macro) and have the results populate below in the spreadsheet

Comment: Did you ever get this working? If not,  I can post some of my personnel code I have written.

Comment: I did get it working. I now need to figure out how to call an excel formula from VBA. For example having VBA run a SQL statement that is contained in cell B1. I tried changing:

.Open "SELECT * FROM table_name" to .open Activeworkbook.activesheet.range("B1") but get ane error stating that the argument is of the wrong type, are out of acceptable range, or are in conflict with eachother. The statement in cell B1 is: SELECT * FROM asys_v_datadictionary order by tableviewname, fieldno

Comment: Declare a string variable, set that variable equal to the cell, and then try putting that variable beside your .Open

Comment: Figured it out! .Open Range("B1").Formula got it working. Thank you WyattTroutman so much for your help