# Call an excel formula from VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

Right now I have an excel spreadsheet with a button assigned to a macro I built that pulls data from SQL server. Right now it only pulls the whole table that I told it to.

The person I am making this for wants it to go further so that they can enter a SQL command in cell B1 and when the button is pressed it will run the statement that is contained in cell b1. So, instead of only being able to run the statement contained within the macro and pull that same table over and over from SQL server the button will be able to run whatever statement is contained within cell B1 making the macro easily changeable.

For example: right now the  macro is pulling all information from the employees table (select * from employees) BUT I want to change that statement to something like (call cell B1) and then it will run whatever is within cell B1 which can be changed very easily without even having to go into VBA.

Comment: If your end user knows sql, why not just give him/her SQL management studio?  Excel seems like a poor repository for sql statements.  What if you saved sql statements in the database and just `EXEC`'d them?

Comment: The user specifically only wants to use front-end sql. Don't ask me why. There are so many other easier ways to grab data from sql into excel but alas I just do what I am assigned.

Answer (score 2):

I would place a call to a public function in the place of the SQL command that you have right now, which I will annote as

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
'dim some objects and file paths, ect
With *some database*
    DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * FROM Employees"
End With
End Sub
```

To the following

```
 Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 'dim objects and file paths again
 With *some database*
     DoCmd.RunSQL(SQLSetup)
 End with
 End Sub

 Public Function SQLSetup() as String
 SQLSetup = Application.ThisWorkBook.Cells(X,Y).Value
 End Sub
```

Of course, there are a ton of ways to improve this. You could break out each element of the SQL statement into a new cell, and concantenate those cell values together in the function. But as far as accessing a value in a cell and passing it into a variable which you can into your SQL statement, this is a rough estimate of what you need.

Comment: I was halfway through writing exactly the same text, only not as good.

Comment: Cronos2546; I have some code I would like you to check out if you have the time. I tried to implement some of your examples into it but am not having any luck. The link is below:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767306/vba-code-cannot-connect-to-sql-server-2008/24768462?noredirect=1#comment38458629_24768462

Comment: Nevermind! Got it working. .Open Range("B1").Formula did the trick ;)